# bash: script doesn't run in the background

Tags: bash, linode

I have a script that performs several linux commands. When I run "./script.sh &" it works fine until I cancel the console. However, when I login again the scritp seems to be running in background but not doing anything.

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to use `nohup` when starting it.

Comment: Thanks. It also worked "./script.sh > output &". It needs to have an output.

Answer (score 1):

```
nohup {command} 0 2>/dev/null &
```

should work for you